# How is MediaPicker implemented on Windows Universal Platform

Tags: win-universal-app, xamarin.forms

**Can anyone provide guidance on how to integrate a camera with Windows Universal Platform?**

Specifically, I need to see how the **MediaPicker** service is implemented.

I have searched tirelessly for a working sample of camera integration with Windows Universal Platform (Windows Phone 10).

I have pulled down XLabs and still don't see support for this platform.

I realize Xamarin.Forms only has a preview version of this.

Comment: The [Xamarin Media Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Media) has Windows support.  Complete source is posted on github

Comment: Thanks. I was able launch the camera from the sample you provided. =)